# How to programatically call a GET API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have two different Spring-boot Microservices which I have created. Service "A" and Service "B". Service A has the following GET API which lets you retrieve a video by its Id.

```
    @RestController
    public class VideoController {

    @Autowired
    VideoService videoService;

    @GetMapping(path = "videos/{videoId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public StreamingResponseBody videoStream(@PathVariable String videoId)
            throws IOException {
        File videoFile = videoService.getVideoById(videoId);
        if (videoFile != null) {
            final InputStream videoFileStream = new FileInputStream(videoFile);
            return (os) -> {
                readAndWrite(videoFileStream, os);
            };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void readAndWrite(final InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
    }

}
```

Service B needs to programatically call the above API.

I have done it using Rest Template and the code is as follows.

```
public Object getVideo(String videoId) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String videoURL = videostoreURL + "/videos/" + videoId;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

    //HttpEntity statusEntity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    Object videoFound = restTemplate.getForObject(videoURL, Object.class);

    return videoFound;
}
```

I have created the Rest controller of service B also similar to the one in service A.

When I call the service B's controller I get the following error in Postman.

```
{
 "timestamp": 1522082255763,
 "status": 406,
 "error": "Not Acceptable",
 "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
 "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
 "path": "/serviceB/videos/sample.mp4"
}
```

How can I fix my REST template?

Comment: 1) What is the point of building `videoURL` if you don't use it? 2) What is the point of creating `statusEntity` if you don't use it? 3) What is `callURL`?

Comment: *FYI:* If you had used a good IDE, it would have told you that `statusEntity` is unused, which is a hint that you did something wrong.

Comment: I created statusEntity to use with restTemplate.exchange method. It gave me the same 406 so I reverted back to restTemplate.getForObject. but I didn't delete the statusEntity line.

Comment: What headers are you sending from postman?

Comment: I have not sent any headers in postman.

Comment: is `/serviceB` meant to be on the front of the client call URL because it's not visible in the code you've shown for the server controller?

Comment: yes the url is correct.